# How to set a button to fill a whole row using gridbox layout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working with Python 3 and PyQt5. I use GridBoxLayout for arranging my buttons. But I need a Button to fill a whole row, which I can't do with GridBoxLayout.

Any one can help?

```
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_startCapture, 0, 0)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_endCapture, 0, 1)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_startRecording, 0, 2)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_endRecording, 0, 3)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_takePicture, 0, 4)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_loadVideo, 0, 5)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.linedit_getPicDir, 1, 0) # I want this button to fill the whole second row
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.linedit_getVideoDir, 2, 1)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_getVideoDir, 2, 2)
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_getPicDir, 2, 3)
```

I get this :

[image]

but I need that the image Dir lien edit be stretched all over the second row

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With QGridLayout you can set a widget to span multiple rows or columns. For example, `addWidget(QPushButton(), 0, 0, 3, 1)`
 will position a button at (0, 0) that spans 3 rows and 1 column.

In your code, you can just add the row and col spans to that line:

```
gridLayout.addWidget(self.linedit_getPicDir, 1, 0, 1, 6)
```